# “score one for truth”

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does “score one for truth” mean?  Googling it gives plenty of examples but no definitions.  It is not clear from context.  A lot of the google results appear to refer to conspiracy theories.  The first google hits:

- First Google hit has [no meaningful context](http://www.collegehumor.com/link/1292372/score-one-for-truth-in), just sais *score one for truth in advertising* with a broken link.
- [Google books result](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=newMTWoKRoUC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=%22Score+one+for+truth%22&source=bl&ots=9oASELb9MW&sig=SUcjArgXwF8gYy76RXFuVIEst3c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi16b-SzdvRAhVsI8AKHXcjDv0Q6AEILzAE#v=onepage&q=%22Score%20one%20for%20truth%22&f=false): *Waiting for you, she said cheerfully. Score one for truth. His gaze slid over her clothes.*
- [Another Google Books result](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ulEcrvRcEDwC&pg=PA69&dq=%22Score+one+for+truth%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbiICaztvRAhWUHsAKHYotCvMQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=%22Score%20one%20for%20truth%22&f=false): *It was enough.  Score one for truth.  The official was now a model of cooperation.*

What does *score one for truth* mean and what are its origins?  What is this *score*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's meant to mean that, in the event being discussed, the truth won over falsehood.

> "I was acquitted in court because I proved I was in hospital when the crime was committed".
>
> "Well, congratulations!  Score 1 for truth!"

The "score" part refers to an imagined game between truth and lies, in which a mark is given on an imaginary scoreboard depending on whether the truth or lies about something is believed (usually, but not always, by authorities). The basis of the game is that lies usually win, so for truth to score is noteworthy.  (See Mark Twain's comment about lies running around the world before truth can get its boots on)

In the case of advertising, adverts are generally based on unsupported claims, so for an advert to state the benefits of the product simply and honestly is quite unusual.

Comment: **"The "score" part refers to an imagined game between truth and lies,"**

I wish I'd said that. It's very clear.

Answer (score 2):

"Score one for [X]" is an idiomatic expression that can be used almost anywhere, to indicate X achieved some kind of victory (over something or someone else).  It's a sports or gaming metaphor, as if the tally between the two sides is kept on a scoreboard.

For example:

> Donald Trump claims that he had the largest crowd ever for his inauguration as President, but side-by-side photos show that Obama's crowd eight years earlier was much, much larger.  *Score one for* photographic evidence!

So, "score one for truth!" means that, this time, the truth won (over some falsehood).

Note: If speaking this phrase, you can punctuate it by using your index finger to mark an imaginary tally on an imaginary scoreboard.

Answer (score 2):

You might also hear this expression expressed in another way. "10 points for your new haircut." You are not actually getting anything. This is usually a compliment and imaginary. I suppose a person could use sarcasm, "10 points for breaking my heart."  So "Score 1" or "10 points" could be viewed as interchangeable IF it saying the phrase was meant as a passing comment.

If there are points involved in a game, then they could be used literally, but this would be uncommon usage and not close to working with your example.